# Windows becomes dim when button press takes longer time

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qframe

How could I prevent the mainwindow goes to dim, even the button click event take long time to response.

For example:
file myframe.h

```
class MyFrame : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit MyFrame(QWidget *parent=0);
~MyFrame();
void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event);
void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

private:
Ui::MyFrame *ui;
}

file myframe.cpp
MyFrame::MyFrame(QWidget *parent):
    QFrame(parent),ui(new Ui::FerryFrame)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void MyFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
// do something cost long time,
// this will make the frame background becomes dim, 

}
MyFrame::~MyFrame()
{
}
```

Any solution?

Thanks,
John

Comment: `QRunnable` / QtConcurrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a thread for long running operations.  You may need to manually gray/dim buttons or other options while your thread runs to prevent the user from issuing the same commands over and over.  See the QT docs for specifics on threading:

[Threading in QT](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html)

Pay special attention to thread pools.  They are useful for GUI events.  Also be aware of complexities of updating the user interface from threads.